# Porting Osmdroid to Monodroid (resolve error and intelli-sense)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, porting, osmdroid

I am porting the jar lib from Osmdroid to Mono for Android (C#). At the moment everything seems to work. I ported the library and included the Binding-Project to my Testproject in order to test the correct porting.

I am able to access the osm libraries, but in MonoDevelop all references are written in red, marked with "resolve errors" and thus there is no Intelli-Sense. Even the "using Osm.xy" is written in red.

But as matter of fact these are just only visual problems. I can build the project and on the emulator everything works as planned.

Can someone tell me, what I can do to get these problems fixed (especially Intelli-Sense)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to add that my problem is solved. 
For everybody who faces problems with porting OsmDroid to Monodroid, meanwhile there exists a tutorial for binding OsmDroid v3.0.8 to Monodroid:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/OsmDroidBindingExample